# Python variables in Jupyter SQL cells

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe that needs to be joined with the result set from a query. The query uses a column from a dataframe to filter the data in the database.

```py
data_list = list(df['needed_column'])
```

I would like to use the variable in an sql query executed in a Jupyter sql cell.

```sql
%%sql
SELECT
    column_1,
    column_2,
    column_3
FROM my_database.my_table
WHERE
    column_1 IN data_list
```

Is there anyway that this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An workaround would be to execute the query inline as a variable.

```py
data_list = str(list(df['needed_column']).replace('[', '(').replace(']', ')')

query_string = f"""
SELECT
    column_1,
    column_2,
    column_3
FROM my_database.my_table
WHERE
    column_1 IN {data_list}
"""

result_set = %sql $query_string
```

Comment: nice workaround

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via Jupysql, there's a simple example on getting and using local variables [here](https://jupysql.ploomber.io/en/latest/user-guide/template.html?highlight=variables#variable-expansion-as-variable).

So basically:

```
dynamic_limit = 5
dynamic_column = "island, sex"
```

```
%sql SELECT {{dynamic_column}} FROM penguins.csv LIMIT {{dynamic_limit}}
```